# Does the sequence $\{c_k\}$ also increases with $k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\binom{K}{k}c_k=\binom{K-1}{k}a_k+\binom{K-1}{k-1}b_k$, where $k=1,2,\cdots,K-1$, $K=2,3,\cdots$. $\{a_k\}$ and $\{b_k\}$ are increasing sequences respectively with $0<b_k<a_k<1$ for every $k=1,2,\cdots,K-1$.

Question: Does the sequence $\{c_k\}$ also increases with $k$?

Will you please give me some hits for this question? Many thanks four kindly help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: It helps to solve for $c_k$:

$$c_k=\frac{\binom{K-1}ka_k+\binom{K-1}{k-1}b_k}{\binom{K}k}=\frac{\binom{K-1}k}{\binom{K}k}a_k+\frac{\binom{K-1}{k-1}}{\binom{K}k}b_k\;.$$

Now set $K=3$, the smallest value that actually gives you more than one term in the $a,b$, and $c$ sequences:

$$\begin{align*}
c_1&=\frac23a_1+\frac13b_1=\frac13(2a_1+b_1)\\
c_2&=\frac13a_2+\frac23b_2=\frac13(a_2+2b_2)
\end{align*}$$

Thus,

$$c_2-c_1=\frac13(a_2-2a_1+2b_2-b_1)\;,$$

and we’ll have a counterexample if we can find $a_1,a_2,b_1$, and $b_2$ such that $0<a_1<a_2<1$, $0<b_1<b_2<1$, $b_1<a_1$, $b_2<a_2$, and

$$a_2-2a_1+2b_2-b_1<0\;.\tag{1}$$

$(1)$ is equivalent to the inequality

$$2a_1+b_1>2b_2+a_2\;.$$

You shouldn’t have too much trouble finding values for $a_1,a_2,b_1$, and $b_2$ that meet the stated conditions *and* satisfy $(1)$.